# Sorting DataFrame by values of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort this dataframe by values of "Score"(from giggest to smalles or vice versa, I just want some order here)
I coded at end:
`models.sort_values(by='Score', ascending=False)`

```
                        Model     Score
0     Support Vector Machines  0.685315
1                         KNN  0.748252
2         Logistic Regression  0.769231
3               Random Forest  0.944056
4                 Naive Bayes  0.769231
5                  Perceptron  0.720280
6  Stochastic Gradient Decent  0.447552
7                  Linear SVC  0.790210
8               Decision Tree  0.727273
```

Obviously my code didn't work, what should I write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort_values` is not in-place by default. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

> DataFrame.sort_values(by, axis=0, ascending=True, **inplace=False**, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')

Either use `inplace=True`:

`models.sort_values(by='Score', ascending=False, inplace=True)`

Or re-assign:

`models = models.sort_values(by='Score', ascending=False)`